# Why does Bodhi break his own rule?

Tags: point-break

In *Point Break* (1991), at the end of the film during their final heist, why does Bodhi break his own rule and have the other Ex-Presidents break into the vault?

He's wasting valuable time, and one of his friends ends up dead as a result.

Was this just a way to toy with Utah?

Comment: I always assumed it was a way to put more pressure on Utah. Maybe to keep him waiting on getting to Tyler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bodhi knew that one way or another, this was the ex-Presidents' last robbery. The FBI was on to them. In order to maintain their surfing lifestyle, they needed to make a big haul. Bodhi is also reinforcing that the rules are what he says they are, as this [exchange](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102685/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu) just before the robbery points out.

> Utah: Bodhi, this is your f__ing wake-up call man. I am an F, B, I,
> Agent!
>
> Bohdi: Yeah, I know man. Ain't it wild? That's what makes it so
> interesting. You can do what you want, and make up your own rules. Why
> be a servant to the law, when you can be its master?